# Why does calling the perspective function leave me with a black screen?

Tags: opengl, haskell

I am using Haskell and OpenGL to construct a 3D terrain. The terrain and lighting are fine, but I am running into some difficulties adjusting the camera / view.

When I run the following code in my `display` function:

```
matrixMode $= Projection
loadIdentity
-- perspective 45 1 0.1 100

matrixMode $= ModelView 0
loadIdentity
lookAt (Vertex3 0 0 0) (Vertex3 0 1 2) (Vector3 0 1 0)
```

I receive the following image:

[image]

But when I uncomment the line

```
perspective 45 1 0.1 100
```

I just get a black screen.

My point array is quite large but here are the last few points copied from `ghci`:

> (1.0,0.0,0.76), (1.0,0.0,0.8), (1.0,0.0,0.84), (1.0,0.0,0.88), (1.0,0.0,0.92), (1.0,0.0,0.96), (1.0,0.0,1.0)

I feel as though:

1. I specify the perspective planes incorrectly? or...
2. I should not be repeatedly calling one or more of these functions?

Comment: Does `glGetError` return any errors?

Comment: @user1118321 I'm not sure if I have access to that function through Haskell's bindings.

Comment: What's in the image you normally see? Looks like a single square, possibly being clipped by near plane? Also, are all of your vertices in `(x, 0, y)` with `0 < x, y < 1`? I suspect that lookAt is your problem. Try `10 10 10` for the first vector (note, you will then see nothing without calling perspective or otherwise setting the far plane).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default projection/viewing volume is orthographic (actually a cube), with the centre at the origin. In a perspective projection, all viewing rays converge to the origin, which is behind the near plane. Since you're origin is on the plane your're drawing, all the vertices will form a line on the screen and won't produce any fragments. As KarolisJuodelė says, adjust the `lookAt` function so that the camera is not on the plane...

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure why but, in my mind, I swapped the argument positions for the first and second vertices... It makes sense now.

Comment: Most epic answer I've seen today!